# default filter mode on react mantine table

Tags: reactjs, react-table, mantine

I am using react mantine table in which for number filter i am using columnFilterModeOptions props for server side filtering. Right now on UI filter mode is coming as undefined, what could be the reason for this? I have defined on of the column as :

````
           accessor: "number",
           accessorFn: (row) => row.data?.number,
           id: "number",
           header: "Votes",
           enableColumnFilterModes: true,
           columnFilterModeOptions: ["equals", "notEquals", "lessThan", "greaterThan", "greaterThanOrEqualTo", "lessThanOrEqualTo"]
         });
      ```
````